# How to override python builtins with an import statement?

Tags: python, python-3.2

I want to log to a text file whatever is `print`ed to `sys.stdout`. While I understand smarter people can come up with more elegant and Pythonic solutions, here is my solution

```
class logger:

  def __init__(self, filename='log.txt'):
    self.logf = open(filename, 'a')

    global print
    self.__print = print

    print = self.lognprint

  def __del__(self):
    self.logf.close()

  def lognprint(self, *args, **keywords):
    self.__print(*args, file = self.logf, **keywords)
    self.__print(*args, **keywords)
```

now if anywhere in my code I add

```
mylog = logger()
```

anything that is `print`ed afterwards is also logged.

But for many obvious reasons this is **not** safe/good. For example multiple `logger` objects can be nasty.

In addition I am inspired by

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

(see [this](http://python3porting.com/noconv.html) for example) and I want to do something similar, so that when I `import` my module, the builtin `print` is overridden by my version of print anywhere in the code.

How is that possible?

Comment: Please tell me you're using this to log `print` output from a 3rd party program that you **can't** change.  If not (== if it's your own code that uses the `print`): Change it to use the [logging](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) module.

Comment: You can always refer to the built-in print function via `__builtins__.print`; no need to capture it in a new variable.

Comment: @LukasGraf 'i am using this to `print` output from a 3rd party program that I **can't** change', _tell me what you want to hear_

Comment: Ok, just wanted to make sure you don't duplicate functionality that's already in the standard library, has excellent documentation and is thread-safe (unlike `print`). :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of placing your code inside the class, put it at the module level. This way it will be executed the first time the module is imported:

```
# logging.py
print = my_print
```

Answer (score 1):

A similar solution, or logging stuff to a file, which also printed to std.out, is given in the [logging cookbook](http://docs.python.org/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-cookbook).
Here is how you can simply log stuff to a file called 'spam.log' and also print certain stuff to std.out:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('simple_example')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# create file handler which logs even debug messages
fh = logging.FileHandler('spam.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# create console handler with a higher log level
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
# create formatter and add it to the handlers
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
# add the handlers to logger
logger.addHandler(ch)
logger.addHandler(fh)

# 'application' code
logger.debug('debug message')
logger.info('info message')
logger.warn('warn message')
logger.error('error message')
logger.critical('critical message')
```

In this example all messages go to the file, only higher levels go to console.